# How to run aerospike AQL from remote servers to query aerospike cluster data

Tags: aerospike, aql

I am trying to run AQL queries on my aerosike cluster from remote servers. 
Please let me know if there any any AQL web/Cli client or any way to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the -h or --host= options to point at one of the hosts in your cluster. Refer to [the AQL docs](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/index.html).